# Why does hook_menu() not show my items in menu?

Tags: routes, hooks

Here's my code and I can't get why `hook_menu` doesn't work. My block menu doesn't showing in menu. As I understood this code (hook_menu()) should show link in which for will work drupal_post_form using function instance_export_form.

So I mean that when I follow admin/config/content/instances_export I get just content menu list, not a form which I need

```
    <?php

function instances_export_block_info()
{
    $blocks['instances_export'] = array(
        'info'  => t('Instance export'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

function instance_export_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['admin/config/content/instance_export/settings'] = array(
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'title'            => 'Configure export',
        'description'      => 'Chose what you want to export and where',
        'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    );

    $items['admin/config/content/instances_export'] = array(
        'title'            => 'Form to export data',
        'page callback'    => 'drupal_post_form',
        'page arguments'   => array('instance_export_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Here info file

```
 name = Instance export and import module
    description = Allow to export synchronize few instance of Drupal
    core = 7.x
    version = «7.x-1.0»
    configure = admin/config/content/instances_export
    files[]=instance_export.module
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) "Doesn't work" isn't a reasonable problem statement, it's ambiguous and doesn't provide any real information about the issue. Please take some time to write a **detailed** question, which covers specifically what "doesn't work" means in this context. Please be sure to include what you _expect_ to happen, what _actually_ happens, error messages you see, and so on. Once there's enough info for someone unfamiliar with your site to be able to help, please flag for re-opening. Many thanks

Comment: @Clive actually doesn't work is quite clear for understating. the hook_menu must show custom elements in menu. doesn't work in this case means, that it doesn't show my items in menu

Comment: Trust me, it isn't clear at all. Why would you expect the above code to produce a block, for example? There's no `hook_block_view()` implementation. What's `drupal_post_form`? Why are you passing page arguments to one router item and not the other? And so on. To be useful to the knowledge repository, questions need to have no ambiguity at all. Only you can provide the context to make this a good question for that repository, which for the free expert help you're going to get, is a pretty fair trade-off.

Comment: As I understood this code (hook_menu()) should show link in which for will work drupal_post_form using function instance_export_form

Comment: Don't tell me, edit the question and put this in the form of prose

Comment: So i mean that when i follow admin/config/content/instances_export i get just content menu list, not a form which I need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42205/discussion-between-tgg132-and-clive).

Comment: See @Clive comment: You are using `drupal_post_form()` as page callback, but Drupal doesn't have that function. Since you had time to correct the shown code, I take you are actually using that code, which contains a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that look out of place there:

1. Your module name is instance_export so you should not use instance_export_form as a function name because Drupal will think that you are defining [hook_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7.x) and you will run into problems. Best to use function names that are less likely to clash with other modules.
2. The menu item `admin/config/content/instance_export/settings` is using [drupal_get_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7.x) as the callback but isn't passing in any form ID as `'page arguments'`
3. The menu item `admin/config/content/instances_export` uses the page callback drupal_post_form(), which is not a Drupal function. I assume you want drupal_get_form() here also.

Something like this should work better:

```
function instance_export_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/content/instance_export/settings'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Configure export',
    'description'      => 'Chose what you want to export and where',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('instance_export_settings_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );

  $items['admin/config/content/instances_export'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Form to export data',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('instance_export_export_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Note that I made up a form function for the first menu item (instance_export_settings_form) and changes the one for the second menu item (instance_export_export_form). This would be whatever you want your functions to be.

Also, if you want these pages to be tabs in your module's admin area do it like this instead:

```
function instance_export_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/content/instance_export'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Configure export',
    'description'      => 'Chose what you want to export and where',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('instance_export_settings_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );

  $items['admin/config/content/instance_export/settings'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Configure export',
    'type'             => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  $items['admin/config/content/instances_export/export'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Form to export data',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('instance_export_export_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

I'm assuming that your hook_block_info() is not relevant to this question.

Comment: I made some assumptions on what you are trying to achieve. This code assumes that you want 2 administration forms, one for export settings and one that is the export form itself.